# Azure APIM does not acknowledge the server url of operations in OpenAPI v3

Tags: azure-api-management

According to [OpenAPI V3](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/), we can define servers at the operation/path level. So, for each operation we can have a different backend.

Unfortunately, it seems Azure APIM is not fully compatible with OpenAPI v3. When importing APIs, it ignores the specified server of operations and sets all the backend urls to the server that is defined at the root level.

Is there any workaround to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No automatic way to import that information. Out of all servers at the root of the spec APIM will take single one as API's backend, rest will be ignored. You can manually go into each operation that has unique backend server and use policies - set-backend and rewrite-uri - to change where request should go for that particular operation.